# Should milk be completely avoided during weight-loss work-outs?

Tags: weight-loss, milk

Milk has a considerable amount of fat. So while in a weight-loss regiment, should milk be avoided completely?

Comment: Why do you think dietary fat should be avoided while trying to improve body composition?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann because a lot of people still believe that consuming fat **makes** you fat.

Comment: Milk may be detrimental to fat loss, but because of the lactose not the milkfat. See [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/720/22) for more on lactose & fat loss.

Comment: This is subjective, but I lost a very significant amount of weight on Atkins and my breakfast during that time was eggs cooked with bacon.  In hindsight not advocating it, just pointing out that you can eat a high fat diet and lose weight...you can also gain on a low fat diet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Eating Fat Does Not Make You Fat

Excess fat on the body is *an entirely different thing* from the fat that you eat. Science and experience agree on this: here's a study entitled [Dietary fat is not a major determinant of body fat](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12566139), and [here's Gary Taubes' overview on the subject](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/07/07/magazine/what-if-it-s-all-been-a-big-fat-lie.html?pagewanted=all&src=pm), appropriate for the layperson. It's a common misconception that eating fat somehow turns into adipose tissue.

Milk might be bad for weight-loss (or it might not), but it wouldn't be because it has a significant proportion of fat. In fact, since fat is satiating--it makes you feel full--I am of the opinion that if one's goal is losing body fat, then fat (like whole-fat milk, or even cream) should be one of the things you eat.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that fat has more Calories per gram (9 Cals/gram Fat).  As long as you don't consume too many Calories, eating a high fat diet isn't going to derail your dieting efforts.

Answer (score -1):

Eating too much fat can derail your dieting efforts. Calorie is a energy and fat is fat. carbs will be burnd durning your workout and through the day and whats left will go as a fat store. 
Fat is FAT is goes straight as a fat store. Use low fat milk instead of full fat.

Comment: That is completely inaccurate. Watch "Fed Up" or do some reading on sugar and insulin.